# Why can't I increase the size of background added to an image?

Tags: css

I have a transparent background image, and I want to add grey color to its background, I did it but I can't extend its width to cver the whole page's width (or in other words, I am not able change its size even after using background-size attribute).

```css
img{
  height:40px;
  width:40px;
  background-color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-size:100px 100px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.google.co.in/search?espv=2&biw=1366&bih=662&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=html+logo+transparent+background&oq=html+logo+tra&gs_l=img.1.1.0j0i30k1.3420.4038.0.5941.4.4.0.0.0.0.302.302.3-1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.img..3.1.301.xRQ23nL94iw#imgrc=FkYJhNmbMb325M%3A" align="center">
```

Comment: because the width/height of your element is only `40x X 40px`

Answer (score 1):

Use a background-image in a parent div

```
    <style>
      .parent {
          width: 100%;
          background-image:url('yourimage.jpg');
          background-position: center center;
          background-color: grey;
        }
    </style>

    <div class="parent">

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change the height and width

```
 img{
       height:100%;
      width:100%;
       }
```

Comment: yes it is of the style of the img try changing  40px to 100%